# Isomorphism of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read that the morphism between affine schemes $(X,O_X)$ and $(Y, O_Y)$
is an isomorphism if and only if it induces an isomorphism of the global sections.
I was interested in proving $\leftarrow$ direction of the statement, bu tI am really stuck. could someone please give me a hint on how to show this?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the ring of global sections for an affine scheme?

Comment: Do you already know that there is a natural bijection between $\operatorname{Hom}(A, B)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec} B, \operatorname{Spec} A)$?

Answer (score 0):

$X=\mathrm{spec}(A)$ and $Y=\mathrm{spec}(B)$.

An  isomorphism (of rings) $f:A=O_X(X)\to B=O_Y(Y)$  induce an isomorphism of schemes $f_{\mathrm{spec}}:(\mathrm{spec}(B),O_{\mathrm{spec}(B)})\to (\mathrm{spec}(B),O_{\mathrm{spec}(B)})$
But $(\mathrm{spec}(B),O_{\mathrm{spec}(B)})=(Y,O_Y)$ and $(\mathrm{spec}(A),O_{\mathrm{spec}(A)})=(X,O_X)$.

Comment: I thought $(X,O_X)$ is an affine scheme means that $(X,O_X) \cong (Spec \ R, O_{Spec \ R})$ for some ring $R$. Can we just let $X = Spec \ A$? Thanks!